# Prove that $a_n = \frac{2^{n^2}}{n!}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question asked was whether the sequence converges or diverges, and it seems clear to me that it diverges. However, I can't seem to put it into a proof. The definition of convergence is

$$ \forall\epsilon > 0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq N\implies |a_n - L| < \epsilon$$

so negating this definition gives

$$ \exists\epsilon > 0,\forall N\in\mathbb{N},\exists n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq N \wedge |a_n - L|\geq \epsilon$$

I really have no idea where to go from here. Also, I was thinking of showing that the sequence is not bounded from above and using the fact that if $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not bounded, then the sequence cannot possibly be convergent. Which one is the correct path to take here?

Answer (score 5):

This sequence will run off to infinity as $n$ gets large. Use the ratio test:
$$
\frac {a_{n}}{ a_{n-1}}=\frac{2^{n^2}/n!}{2^{(n-1)^2}/(n-1)!}=\frac{2^{n^2}}{n2^{(n-1)^2}}=\frac{2^{2n-1}}{n}.
$$
Can you conclude?

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't think of that... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not a problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Since
$$
\lim_n\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_n\frac{2^{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)!}\cdot\frac{n!}{2^{n^2}}=\lim_n\frac{2^{(n+1)^2-n^2}}{n+1}=\lim_n\frac{2^{2n+1}}{n+1}=\infty,
$$
there is an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \ge 2 \quad \forall n \ge N.
$$
It follows that
$$
a_n \ge 2^{n-N}a_N \quad \forall n \ge N.
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_na_n\ge a_N\lim_n2^{n-N}=\infty,
$$
i.e. $\lim_na_n=\infty$.

Comment: I must be really out of it if I can't recall the ratio test. Thanks a lot.